# NSApplescript will not accept initWithContentsOfURL

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript

I am new to this so please bear with me.
My problem is in the following code:

AppleScriptController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>        
@interface AppleScriptController : NSObject    
-(void)test;
@end
```

AppleScriptController.m

```
#import "AppleScriptController.h"    
@implementation AppleScriptController

-(void)test{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep" 
                                                 ofType:@"scpt"];    
    NSAppleScript *script2 = [[NSAppleScript alloc]
                          initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] 
                          error:nil];    
    [script2 executeAndReturnError:nil];    
}
@end
```

(A copy of beep.scpt is in the Supporting files)

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppleScriptController.h"

AppleScriptController *myScript = [[AppleScriptController alloc] init];
[myScript test];
```

When I run it I get the following error message:
Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

```
NSAppleScript *script2 = [[NSAppleScript alloc]
                          initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] 
                          error:nil];    Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"
```

and get the following error code:

> 2013-01-02 23:09:09.269 Test8[1627:707] *** Terminating app
>
> due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>
> reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string
>
> parameter'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8db7df56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff95dfbd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8db7dd8a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>
> 3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8db7dd14 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
>
> 4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fd6ae40 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 78
>
> 5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fd6add9 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 47
>
> 6   Test8                               0x0000000100000d9d -[AppleScriptController test] + 205
>
> 7   Test8                               0x0000000100000cac main + 108
>
> 8   Test8                               0x0000000100000c34 start + 52
>
> 9   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>
> )
>
> terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>
> Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
>
> (gdb)

The program works fine when I change the m-file to initWithSource:

```
NSAppleScript *script1 = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"beep 10"];
[script1 executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

I run XCode 4.2.1 on OS X 10.7.5

Please advice me where I went wrong. I am sure it is some kind of newbie mistake but I can't seem to be able to find it.

Any advice gratefully received!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error code:

```
reason: '* -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string
```

So here:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep" 
                                             ofType:@"scpt"];    
NSAppleScript *script2 = [[NSAppleScript alloc]
                      initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] 
                      error:nil];
```

path is nil. So with all probabilities the file is not in the bundle. Add it as target of the project.

**How to do it**

For example last day I need to add the image of a shark in the bundle, that's how to do it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for narrowing it down. Just one more question. How can the path be nil when I have added the script file into the Supporting files? What did I do wrong?

Comment: @user1943875: "Supporting Files" is just the name of a group of files. It does not mean that all of the files will be packaged into your application. You can remove the "Supporting Files" group altogether and use a different group. All that matters is that the file's target membership includes the correct target.

Comment: @Remy, After starting all over I was able to add the script file as a target, but unfortunately all the problems remain as before. I get the same error messages.

Comment: I have no idea what just happened, but it is working now. Thank you very much for your time and knowledge!!